# Jquery Ajax to Web Api CORS is not working

Tags: jquery, cors, asp.net-web-api

I have the following jquery code

```
 $('#spam').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.my-contacts.com/contacts/api/contacts',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        headers: { 'Authorization=': 'Bearer ' },

    }).done(function () {
        alert("success");
    })
.fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(xhr);
    alert("Error:" + xhr);
});
});
```

The browser send the preflight request with options and get a 200 from the server (I have arranged with a handler that is called). Below are the headers

```
**Response Headers view source**
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    Authorization, X-Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
Cache-Control   no-cache
Content-Length  0
Date    Fri, 13 Dec 2013 12:01:18 GMT
Expires -1
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET

**Request Headers view source**
  Accept    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Encoding   gzip, deflate
  Accept-Language   en-US,en;q=0.5
  Access-Control-Request-He...  content-type
  Access-Control-Request-Me...  GET
  Connection    keep-alive
  Host  www.my-contacts.com
  Origin    http://www.my-promo.com
  User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
```

The problem is that the browser is supposed to continue with the GET request but nothing happens and I receive and error from the .error() Jquery Code.

Any pointers?

**EDIT**

It turns out that there were many reasons why the above did not work. However it finally came down to JQuery not working well with CORS (at least the version that I am using 1.8.2 but I tried 1.10 too)

I changed the code with

```
(function () {
            x = new XMLHttpRequest();
            x.open('GET', 'http://www.my-contacts.com/contacts/api/contacts', false);
            x.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (x.readyState === 4) {
                    console.info(x.responseText);
                }
            };
            x.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
            x.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
            x.send('');
        })();
```

But this code does not work with IE or FF. Chrome on the other hand works perfectly. The other two give me an error with `x.send('')`

Comment: Do you have more details about the xhr object, textStatus and errorThrown in `.fail`?

Comment: I always try the API requests using some tools (fiddler, postman rest client) before trying it with ajax..

Answer (score 0):

Is hard to say what is wrong without looking the configuration of the services. Is really tricky getting this to work. This link helps me alot into this. He is configuring a WCF service, but i think its worth reading..

[Implementing CORS support in WCF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Implementing-CORS-support-c1f9cd4b)